# AngularJS: Prevent hidden form fields being validated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

What is the best way of preventing hidden form fields being validated in AngularJS?

Comment: so may be just remove its `required` attribute when you're hiding it?

Comment: if you have code, please post it to help us, there is enough options to implement your logic, but sure not from scratch but just change your code. Fiddle/PLunker will be great

Comment: is there anyone that answer your question? many are just giving you the option to disable required validation but not any other... like, number... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I initially missed the built-in `ngRequired` directive. There is a `required` tag as well, which confused me.

Now, we can use the same logic (which we used to hide the element) to set the `ngRequired` false.

Here is an example practical usecase: I want to ask married people the number of children they have, but, if they are not married, simply hide the field about children.

```
<form ng-app name="form">

    Marital status:
    <select  ng-model="maritalStatus" required>
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="M">Married</option>
        <option value="UM">Unmarried</option>
    </select>

    <div ng-show="maritalStatus == 'M'">
        Number of children: <input type="number" ng-model="children"  ng-required="maritalStatus == 'M'">
    </div>

    (for testing) Is this form correctly filled? {{form.$valid}}

</form>
```

Comment: It's so easy, thank you. I have a subform which was preventing the main form from being valid, because the subform (which wasn't visible) had a text-field which had the ng-required="true" directive. Now everything works as expected!

Comment: This will totally work; just note that ng-if creates an isolate scope...if you don't take that into account that could cause some undesired affects.

Comment: Here a situation - First I select Married and entered the no. of children's and  later select Unmarried. Now when I submit the form the children value is also getting submitted. How do I prevent submitting the value of children's ?

Comment: Got confused with the required attribute and used required="expression" instead of using ng-required="expression". Thanks @siva636

Answer (score 46):

You may also completely add or remove it from the DOM/form by using ng-if instead of ng-show.

```
<div ng-show="maritalStatus === 'M'">
    Number of children: <input type="number" ng-model="children"  ng-required="maritalStatus == 'M'">
</div>
```

to this

```
<div ng-if="maritalStatus === 'M'">
    Number of children: <input type="number" ng-model="children"  ng-required="true">
</div>
```

Comment: ng-if works well if you want to avoid validation on more than one element or when your validation is more complex than just checking if element's not empty. This is assuming you want to hide element as well.

Comment: so basically you are removing everything, even the user input??

Comment: The entire div and the contents in this place, but you could also use ng-if on the input as well and skip the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `required` attribute by using directives:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">   
 <input type="backbutton" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text"  required/>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('input',function($compile){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    compile:function($tElement,$tAttrs){
        console.log("hi there");
      var el = $tElement[0];
      if(el.getAttribute('type')){
        el.removeAttribute('type');
        el.setAttribute($tAttrs.type,'');
        return function(scope){
          $compile(el)(scope);
        }
      }

    }  
  }
});


app.directive('remove',function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace:true,
    template:'',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          element.removeAttr('required');
      }
  }
});
```

See <kbd>[Fidlle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WptGC/25/)</kbd>

Before:

```
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" required="" remove="" class="ng-scope">
```

After:

```
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" remove="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: The fidlle does nothing!?

Comment: it removes `required` from `input`. You can debug it and check that on start you have ``required`.

Comment: ahhh ok sorry haven't noticed it.