# how to stop validation on a particular textbox after hiding this textbox using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have there textbox and one submit button..and two radio buttons..radio buttons are used for show/hide a textbox1..my problem is that after selecting radio buttons textbox1 is hiding..i have added a validation on button ng-click..it is working fine..but after hiding the textbox the validation is still working if i dont put any data in textbox1..
my code is given below..

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm" method="get">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server" TextMode="Email" required  ng-model="EmailID" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtsubject" runat="server" ng-model="Subject"   required></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="editor"  runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ng-model="Message" Rows="10"  required></asp:TextBox>

<button ng-click="myform.$valid && SendMailData()"  id="sendmail" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Send">Send</button>
```

i have show hide the textboxes using this jquery function

```
$("#txtto").hide();
```

my problem is that validation is still working after hiding the textboxes...
can anyone help me please????i want to stop validation for this textbox after hiding this textbox.......

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/19133362/1868660

Comment: <input type="radio" id="optradio2" name="optradio2">Group

Comment: here is my radio button for hiding 'txtto' textbox..can you help me plese how to write ng-required field by clicking this particular radio button

Comment: can you modified my ng-required code please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-if` instead of `$("#txtto").hide();`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server" TextMode="Email" required  ng-model="EmailID" ng-if="radioValue == 'showText'"></asp:TextBox>
```

Where `expression` is your angularjs expression to show/hide the tag.

Could apply below logic::

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="radioValue" ng-value="showText">
<input type="radio" ng-model="radioValue" ng-value="HideText">
```

Comment: what i have to write in expression??

Comment: how to write the function

Comment: actually i have two radio button one radio button is used for showing all textbox and button1 and another textbox is using for hide a txtto textbox and hide button1 and show button2

Comment: I have updated the asnwer, you can do related changes and make it work for you.